# Facebook Insights about post

Tags: facebook, metric

I am trying to retrieve metrics `post_impressions_unique`, `post_consumptions` or anything started with a `post` but Facebook always return empty array for me.

Anyone know what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have the right permissions?

You need read_insight permissions to view post impressions using fql or the graph api.

Here is more information [Facebook Developer Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/)

Comment: Yes I have the permission, I can view other metrics without issue such as page_views/page_stories, only those start with post_something.

Answer (score 0):

As well as needing the read_insights permission, this information is only available for posts made by your page, so check you're actually checking the right posts

Comment: yup, the object ID is correct, I can retrieve all the entries in "stream" and their impression. But when I try to retrieve post_impressions metric from insight table, it return empty array without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass in the entire object ID of the post.  It will be of the format pageid_postid (eg. 24379523495_8924592457245) and you need to quote it in single quotes - otherwise you'll get an error about an unexpected underscore.